# vb script to check file owner by comparing list with possible owners

Tags: command-line, vbscript, command-prompt

I am bad/new in scripting and I did not find any script that does the following:

1. I have an "allowed.txt" file with names of people who are allowed to change/modify files. i.e.

   ```
   administrator
   computername\UsernameA
   computername\UsernameB
   ```
2. Now I wish a script that reads this textfile and compares all file-owners(changers) on a machine with the names in this list. All Files that were changed by computername\UsernameC (who is not listed in my list of allowed users) Should be parsed in an "output.txt" file with 
   "filepath\filename - change by "computername\UsernameC - changed date"

The problem is the following: We have people working on a pc and they manipulate files while working on a pc. It would be too much work to check each file by hand to find the files that were changed by people who are not entitled to do so.

So it would be a great help if I run this script and find all files that were changed by people that are not listed in my text file.

We do *not* want to use Windows File auditing.

Is there any chance to get/write a vbs script that can achieve this?

Comment: Isn't the real root cause that you have bad access management implemented? What you are asking is just a work around. It seems to me that the real answer is: Implement correct user authorization on your workstations.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be achieved without SACLs (i.e. file/folder auditing), because the information *who* accessed/changed a particular file is not stored otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will then have no other way than to stick to auditing.